# Problem with design in OOP (Virtual member call in constructor)

Tags: oop

I am trying to achieve something like the following:

```
class Foo
{
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }

    public Foo(int n)
    {
        Number = n;  //Virtual member call in constructor
    }

    public void Do() {
        Console.WriteLine(Number);
    }

}

class Bar : Foo
{
    public override int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return x.Val;
        }
        set
        {
            x.Val = value;
        }
    }

    Bar(int n) : base(n)
    {
        X x = new X();
        x.Val = n;
    }

    public void F() {
        x.Something();  //changes x.Val
    }
}
```

The reason I am doing this is because I need to propagate the call to `Do` when called from a variable of type `Bar`.

Now, I can have objects that either inherit from `Foo` or `Bar`, thus `Number` needs to be the way it is now, ie directly expose the `Val` property of `x`. This is because I need to allow for the following code:

```
Bar b = new Bar(5);
b.F(); //changes the value of Val in x
b.Do(); //Needs to print the correct, modified value
```

The problem here is obviously in `Foo`, when assigning `n` to `Number` (`Virtual member call in constructor`) since `x` from the subclass would not have been initialized yet.

---

What do you think is a better way to structure such a design?

I can't use this current code because I am calling a virtual member from the constructor, which causes the `Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object` exception since `x` in `Number` from `Bar` would not have been yet initialized.

Comment: It is bad practice to call non-final methods from super class constructors.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking for an alternative design

Answer (score 0):

My favorite quote:

> Favor composition over inheritance

I would separate underlying data from operations:

```
interface IMyNumber
{
   int Number { get; set; }

   void Something();
}

class MyNumber : IMyNumber
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public MyNumber(int n)
    {
        Number = n;
    }

    void Something() {... }
}

class MyBoxedNumber : IMyNumber
{ 
    int Number { get { ... } set {... } }

    void Something() {... }
}

class Bar
{
    private IMyNumber_foo;

    Bar(IMyNumber foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    public void F() {
        _foo.Something();  //changes x.Val
    }

    public void Do() {
        Console.WriteLine(...)
    }
}
```